# FSCalendar - Custom HeaderView, WeekDayView

Tags: swift, fscalendar

I am using FSCalendar in my project and I want to achieve a custom appearence of calendar. I read the documentation and looked for the answer on stackoverflow but still cannot find the answer.

---

**Is it possible to customize HeaderView (displayed month) or WeekDaysView (labels of weekdays) without editing existing FSCalendar code? For example HeaderView would contain buttons or WeekDaysView would have borders?**

---

I guess this is possible by editing directly FSCalendar code but the problem is that it is programmed in Objective-C (since I am not really familiar with Obj-C I am looking for a swift solution). I also read some tips that it can be done by overlapping custom views but it does not seem right to me.

Is there a way to customize these views in swift? Is it possible to do so as it may be done with Custom Cell, when it can be a subclass of FSCalendarCell? (There is no need to change existing FSCalendar library code). How do people customize FSCalendar? There are tons of projects which use this framework and have completely custom styles.

Answer (score 0):

```
let vwHead = FSCalendarHeaderView()
vwHead.backgroundColor = .DarkBlue
self.calendar.calendarHeaderView = vwHead
```

and you can customize header of Calender Accordingly

Comment: This solution does not work. HeaderView disappears.

Answer (score 0):

As a new user of FScalendar, I am hoping my belated could be of assistance.

option 1
It is clear that FScalendar does have "limited" features as shown below. You can download FSCalendar github file and look into `FSCalendarAppearance`, `FSCalendarHeaderView`.

[image]
[image]

option 2

Above answer's solution would have worked. If this was the case. But if you want to add a button, you have to create a separate class of `FSCalendarCell` and connect them to your calendar.

```
self.calendar.calendarHeaderView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
```

option 3

**If that's too much work, you can simply create an overlapping UIbutton or view (on top of the calendarView) to create custom method that will trigger FSCalendar Delegate methods**.